# Radial Waves in Processing

Tags: loops, nested, processing

I am currently a bit stuck! Lets say, have a grid of shapes (nested For-Loop) and I want to use a wave to animate it. The wave should have an offset. So far, i can achieve it. Currently the offset affects the Y-axis … But how can I manage to have a RADIAL offset – you know – like the clock hand, or a radar line… I really would like the offset to start from (width/2, height/2) – and then walks around clockwise. Here is my code and the point where I am stuck:

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw () {
  background(255);
  float tiles = 60;
  float tileSize = width/tiles;
  for (int x = 0; x < tiles; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < tiles; y++) {
      float waveOffset = map(y, 0, 60, 0, 300);      
      float sin = sin(radians(frameCount + waveOffset));
      float wave = map(sin, -1, 1, 0, tileSize);
      fill(0);
      noStroke();
      pushMatrix();
      translate(tileSize/2, tileSize/2);
      ellipse(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, wave, wave);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
}
```

I tried different things – like the rotate(); function etc. but I can't manage to combine it!
Thank you for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're defining the size of the ellipses based on a transformation of `sin(y)`. A transformation means it looks like `a * sin(b * y + c) + d`, and in this case you have

- `a = tileSize / 2`
- `b = 300 / 60 = 5`
- `c = frameCount`
- `d = tileSize / 2`

If you want to do a different pattern, you need to use a transformation of `sin(theta)` where `theta` is the "angle" of the dot (I put "angle" in quotes because it's really the angle from the vector from the center to the dot and some reference vector).

I suggest using the [`atan2()`](https://processing.org/reference/atan2_.html) function.

Solution:

```java
float waveOffset = 2*(atan2(y - tiles/2, x - tiles/2));
float sin = sin((frameCount/20.0 + waveOffset));
```

Comment: YESSS! This is it – OMG – I could never done this on my own... Thank you so much!
Below i did i slight change to the code, check it out:

Answer (score 1):

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw () {
  background(255);
  float tiles = 60;
  float tileSize = width/tiles;
  for (int x = 0; x < tiles; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < tiles; y++) {
      float waveOffset = atan2(y - tiles/2, x - tiles/2)*0.5;      
      float sin = sin((frameCount*0.05 + waveOffset));
      float wave = map(sin, -1, 1, 0, tileSize);
      fill(0);
      noStroke();
      pushMatrix();
      translate(tileSize/2, tileSize/2);
      ellipse(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, wave, wave);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
}
```